# Parents name change before ILR-SET(M) application

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, paperwork

I'm currently on FLR-M and going to apply for ILR(SET-M) in a few months, the problem is my parents have changed their names, Will different parent names in my previous application and current application cause issues? My Indian passport has their old name endorsed on it. Also, should I get my Indian passport changed? Is there any helpline I can contact? I understand this is a very rare situation but any help is appreciated.

2. Also, I will be applying for my parents' visit visa will different names in my passport and their passport cause issues in that?

Answer (score 0):

I recently filled ILR(SET-M) form for my partner, and there was no question to specifically ask parents' names in that form. So you don't have to worry there.
Although If you still want to convey this information, you can always provide information in the cover letter.